# Jquery mobile - scroll to bottom automatically after page is loaded

Tags: spring, jquery-mobile

I'm building a peer-to-peer chat. Whenever I open the chat (means after server-roundtrip) the suiting jsp will be displayed decided by a spring-controller. The latest chat comment is at the bottom of the scrollable page. 
Unfortunately when page is loaded there's no reaction to the jquery method like

```
$(document).scrollTop(1000);
```

to get to the bottom of the page.

I also put this method inside `pageInit` and `pageBeforeShow` events of jqm. But in vain.

What's wrong?

Comment: What does the HTML structure look like? Are you sure it's document that needs to scroll? If the overflow that you need to scroll to the bottom to is something other than document then it's that element you need to scroll (may be a stupid question, but it's worth clarifying the simple things first!)